# jQuery script fails in IE and Opera

Tags: jquery, html

http://dev.mindboiler.lv/ (you'll be taken to intro page, just click on logo to get into real site)

This is website I'm currently working on. You can change the language to English to understand it a little better, but anyways, it's full of dummy text.
There are these `Read more` links which, when clicked, execute the following jQuery:

```
$('.content-item .readmore').toggle(function() {
    parent = $(this).parent();
    $(parent).children('div.next').fadeIn();
    $(this).html("Read less &raquo;");
}, function() {
    parent = $(this).parent();
    $(parent).children('div.next').fadeOut();
    $(this).html("Read more &raquo;");
});
```

Firefox, Safari, Chrome works like a charm, but Internet Explorer (all versions) and Opera doesn't want to execute it properly.

Any solutions for this to work in IE and Opera?

P.S. Not a JavaScript/jQuery guru, therefore the script looks like crap.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Sometimes, if something doesn't work in IE _and_ Opera, it's an indication that your markup structure is wrong, rather than the script (if it only doesn't work in IE, that's probably an indication that you're writing great, standards-compliant code.) Have you validated the page? http://validator.w3.org

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears as though your `<div class="next">` is a sibling to your `<div class="content-item">` so why even bother with the parent() function.

Simplify it to this and see if it works:

```
$('.content-item .readmore').toggle(function() {        
    $(this).next().fadeIn();
    $(this).html("Read less &raquo;");
}, function() {
    $(this).next().fadeOut();
    $(this).html("Read more &raquo;");
});
```

Comment: Since `Read more` link is the last child element of `.content-item` it won't work with `.next()`, but yeah, changing it to `.prev()` did the trick! Thanks for pointing in the right direction, accepted!